# Dexie is not Defined

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

[Reference Error: Dexie is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecqrf.png)
 I haave attached the screenshot of the error. Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included dexie.js for your app. Seems you've only included ngDexie so far.

Answer (score 0):

When using ngDexie with bower or npm it will automaticly install the right (tested with ngDexie) version of dexie.js. I would recommend that way.

However if you inject it manual, you should also inject dexie manual.